# eloquent: How to load and set model variables, inside the model itself?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

Laravel documentation suggests the following way to set up an eloquent model:

```
$user = user::with($conditions)->first();
```

What if I want to set up my eloquent model inside the model itself:

```
$user = new user();
$user->setup($conditions);
// class definition
class user extends Eloquent{
    public function setup($conditions){
        // load current object with table data
        // something like
        $this->where($conditions)->first();
        // previous line output is dangling, is ok to assign it to $this variable?
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: after running first code sample, `$user->id` and other column variables are accessible (and most likely they are not empty), but in second one `$user` is an empty object, how can I load this object up with column variables after calling `setup` method?

Comment: To load current object with table data, it should know which row to load from the table. So how you will provide that information. In the first code, you are saying to load the first row from the data whereas in the second one your not specifying the row. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There is a conditions input in setup method, I updated the question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're extending from Eloquent model, you may try the following approach. I assume you have a unique `id` column.

```
public function setup($conditions)
{
    $model = self::with($conditions)->first();

    if (! is_null($model)) {
        $this->exists = true;
        $this->forceFill(self::find($model->id)->toArray());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: this answer returns a totally new object, but it does not load the current object.

Comment: Just updated my previous solution, this way your `setup()` method will load the model data.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly fine, But I still hope someone suggest a more robust solution!